# Running vagrant up can't access the registered map in the Homestead.yaml

Tags: php, git, bash, laravel, laravel-5

I just install Homestead on my project named **LaravelFrancis** under `C:\xampp\htdocs` using Git Bash I installed the Homestead directly in my project

```
composer require laravel/homestead --dev
```

After installing I used `make` command to generate Vagrantfile and Homestead.yaml

```
vendor\\bin\\homestead make
```

This is my Homestead.yaml looks like.

```
---
  ip: "192.168.10.10"
  memory: 2048
  cpus: 1
  hostname: LaravelFrancis
  name: LaravelFrancis
  provider: virtualbox

  authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

  keys:
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

  folders:
      - map: C:\xampp\htdocs\LaravelFrancis
        to: /home/vagrant/LaravelFrancis

  sites:
      - map: dms.dev
        to: /home/vagrant/LaravelFrancis/plublic

  databases:
      - homestead

  # blackfire:
  #     - id: foo
  #       token: bar
  #       client-id: foo
  #       client-token: bar

  # ports:
  #     - send: 50000
  #       to: 5000
  #     - send: 7777
  #       to: 777
  #       protocol: udp
```

**etc/hosts/**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.10.10 dms.dev
```

After running vagrant up in the Git Bash terminal. It says.

[image: SC]

Any help why it won't enter me to the registered sites that I register?